# Ragnar's injury after the Paris battle

Tags: character, vikings

In *Vikings*, in the first attack on Paris, Ragnar jumps from the tower, hits his back on one of the siege towers and then hits the pile of dead bodies. After this, it is shown that he is injured, but it's never said what kind of injury he really has.

From what we see, it's not the spine (he can walk), but rather something internal like liver or kidney damage. Later on, he's seen having bloody urine and vomiting. His coughing seems to be a symptom of a lung injury.

Can someone give more hints or a better diagnosis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He suffered from Kidney failure. Failure of a kidney can result in severe discomfort in the abdomen, bloody urine, and waste production build up which can cause illness, hallucinations and nausea. But even though he suffered from kidney failure, surviving with just 1 kidney is entirely possible. Some people are born with only 1. It is even possible to survive with no kidneys.

Comment: how can someone survive with no kidneys?