# Is Ragnar's posture in "Vikings" due to a character injury or his actor recovering from one?

Tags: character, vikings

I'm watching the *Vikings* season where Ragnar creates an alliance with King, Ecbert,. But it started quite a while back, Ragnar seems to lean whenever he stands,  lie down instead of sitting,  etc. I do the same because of pain and weakness in my lower back.

1. Is this because Ragnar has an injury,  or
2. Because the actor is recovering from one?

I'm still researching it and may find my own answer but I enjoy other's perspectives.

Comment: Possibly related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89664/ragnars-injury-after-the-paris-battle

Answer (score 3):

Ragnar's political game generally revolves around him playing the role of a rather happy and naive simple man. He only reveals his aptitude and ambitions much later, when he can't get around it anymore or revealing it is beneficial in some way.
He often eeks out a victory because he is dismissed/ignored by those who consider themselves superior. They undervalue Ragnar's worth as an opponent, and Ragnar uses that to his advantage.

His posture help sell the idea of Ragnar not being regnal. Compared to the kings and nobility, he comes across as not being smart/noble enough to rule his people efficiently. He portrays a generally blasé and nonchalant attitude that is key to selling his "simple Ragnar" persona.